# Using regex in pactdsl request body

Tags: java, integration-testing, pact, pact-jvm

I want my pact server to return a custom response when making a POST call with Header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. 
However, the body of the POST call is not always the same, only a prefix remains constant. 
For example, It has to return the same thing, whether I call it with body
 `input_text=LOGSomeStuffHERE`, or with `input_text=LOGAnoutherStuff` 
(As you see, `input_text=LOG` is the constant part)
This is what I have tried:

```
.uponReceiving("POST cusom body")
.path("/path")
.method("POST")
.headers(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.getMimeType())
.body("input_text=LOG*")
.willRespondWith()
.status(200)
...
```

Does PactDsl support some kind of body matching on the request part?

Comment: I have also tried using `.body(new PactDslJsonBody()...)`, but that doesn't work either, because the request's Content-Type is not `aplication/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [match using a Regex](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit#dsl-matching-methods) to validate your body.  The `body` itself in the DSL is the actual body (with fake data) that is suppose to be returned for an interaction, without actually adding extra matchers. If you want an [example of this, look at the test code for the jvm consumer](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-consumer/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/PactDslRootValueTest.java).

In your case, you'd do:

```
.uponReceiving("POST cusom body")
.path("/path")
.method("POST")
.headers(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
   ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.getMimeType())
.body(PactDslJsonRootValue.stringMatcher("^input_text\=LOG.*", 
   "input_text=LOG_something"))
.willRespondWith()
.status(200)
```

The first argument is a string representation of the regex, while the second is the string to actually pass for the interaction, which need to pass the regex test.